# i have a problem with my code and i'm not sure if i even wrote it correctly

Tags: c

so i'm practicing c and  i built a program that says if its prime number or not  and i tried to execute it but it wont work it doesnt shows me the output oh and im still new to this i started learning  c one week ago.

i dont know how to fix this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Num();

int main()
{
  void Num();

  return 0;
}

void Num()
{
  int n, i, flag = 0;

  printf("Enter a num: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    for(n = 1; n <= 10; n++)
    {
      flag = 1;
    }
  }

  if( flag == 1)
  {
    printf("its not the prime num ");
  } else{
    printf("its the prime num" );
  }
}
```

it wont even show the printf output

Comment: Note that the function `Num()` sets `flag = 1` a hundred times but does not make any test for primality. Also, the inner loop overwrites the value entered for `n`.

Comment: `void Num();` in `main` should be `Num();`. Then you need to fix the other faults with your debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back to the basics (this means: reading a good C book before diving in). You are confusing *declaration* and *calling* of functions.

```
int main()
{
  void Num();

  return 0;
}
```

`main` contains two statements:

1. A local (re)declaration of `Num` as a function without return value.
2. A `return` statement.

Since you want to *call* `Num` rather than redeclaring it, you need to use the function call syntax:

```
int main()
{
  Num();
  return 0;
}
```

This is just the first step, however. Your `Num` function does not perform the correct actions to determine primality.